# Changing a ListBoxItems mouse over style in Xaml/Wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I am trying to change a `ListBox` so that when I mouse over it, it no longer shows the default `IsMouseOver` `style`.

From my searching online the suggested code looks something like this;

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ExampleItems}">

    ...

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
              <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
              <Style.Triggers>
                   <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                       <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gold"/>
                       <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Purple"/>
                   </Trigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

This code produces the correct results for initial coloring, that is to say the items are displayed with a red `Background` and a blue `Border`;

[Before MouseOver Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpgeT.png)

but the `IsMouseOver` trigger still shows the default styling;

[After MouseOver Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vleB3.png)

I know the colors are awful, this is simply just for demonstration purposes. Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:**
As has been answered I have found the `ControlTemplate` (Via the Properties-Misc panel), however I am now unsure how to set the `ControlTemplate` of a `ListBoxItem` that I can't see in the Xaml. The `ListBoxItems` are created once the program is running via the `ItemSource` Binding, is there a way of setting the `ControlTemplate` for `ListBoxItems` of a data bound `ListBox`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the template for the listboxitem.
To get a copy of that, add a ListBoxItem into any window.

Select it in the XAML.
Look over in the property window for it's properties.
Find the Miscellaneous section.
In there is Template.
Click the box to the right and create as a resource.
What you get ( in win 10 ) is this:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ListBoxItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#1F26A0DA"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#A826A0DA"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#3DDADADA"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFDADADA"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#3D26A0DA"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

You can either make your own template completely, or change some of those colours to taste.
Then apply it to all listboxitems (setter property template value ...) in your listbox using a style or setting the default controltemplate via style.

At a higher level to wherever you have your listbox. Or in app.xaml.

Here's an example in window resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Pink"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#A826A0DA"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Red"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFDADADA"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Orange"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That's great, thank you so much! Didn't think to look in the 'ControlTemplate' been looking for a couple of hours now!

Comment: I have edited the question for others to answer possibly, however do you know the answer at all?

Comment: I added that to my post.

Comment: So I put that code into my App.xaml and the application crashes on startup, the issue being the `x:key="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"` since removing this allows the application to run.

Comment: **Edit** It's not the key that causes it to crash but rather the code for the control. I copied this directly from the `Create as new resource`?

Comment: I tried this in a window, spotted the issue and added working markup above.

Comment: That's great works perfectly, I assume the problem was that it had two templates and it was trying to assign both? This overrides the default instead of providing a second? Thanks for your help, much appreciated!